# How do I execute a custom flow trigger from a plugin in Shopware >=6.5?

Tags: php, symfony, events, shopware, shopware6

Somehow/somewhere a flow trigger has to be executed, right? But I can't tell how. The docs are both lacking and outdated in that regard.

I got the trigger to show up in the Flow Builder, so I can assign an action for it, like adding a tag to an order. But if I then try to execute my event something like this somewhere in my plugin:

```
$this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(new OrderSentEvent($order, $context));
```

…the event dispatcher doesn't seem to know what to do with it
because `${dispatcher}->hasListeners($eventName)` comes up empty so it ends up in its `orphanedEvents` property. The event class is defined like this:

```
class OrderSentEvent extends Symfony\Contracts\EventDispatcher\Event implements Shopware\Core\Framework\Event\OrderAware{}
```

What am I missing? This is the outdated guide I followed: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/flow/add-flow-builder-trigger.html

There is no `BusinessEventInterface` anymore in v6.5, for example and I'm not sure what to make of that. I'm under the impression that if I'm just using the existing `OrderAware`, I don't have to create my own `Storer`, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(new OrderSentEvent($order, $context), 'name.goes.here');
```

…did the trick. No event subscriber could be found, because if you don't provide a name as 2nd argument, the full class name will be used, but the Flow Builder apparently uses the custom one.